Don't remove trailing spaces in pug secitons of Vue files
VS Code removes trailing spaces automatically, which is mostly good.
But in Vue files with sections in pug (<template lang="pug">), the trailing space is significant and should not be removed.
I tried this in settings.json but it doesn't work:
"[pug]": {
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false,
  },

Presumably because the file itself is not a pug file.
How can I make this setting apply to pug sections of other files?
